# Await in catch block fails inside forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, async-await, try-catch

I have an array-like structure that exposes async methods. The async method calls contain try-catch blocks which in turn expose more async methods in the case of caught errors. I'd like to understand why `forEach` doesn't play nicely with `async`/`await`.

```
let items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

// Desirable behavior
processForLoop(items);
/* Processing foo
 * Resolved foo after 3 seconds.
 * Processing bar
 * Resolved bar after 3 seconds.
 * Processing baz
 * Resolved baz after 3 seconds.
 */

// Undesirable behavior
processForEach(items);
/* Processing foo
 * Processing bar
 * Processing baz
 * Resolved foo after 3 seconds.
 * Resolved bar after 3 seconds.
 * Resolved baz after 3 seconds.
 */

async function processForLoop(items) {
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        await tryToProcess(items[i]);
    }
}

async function processForEach(items) {
    items.forEach(await tryToProcess);
}

async function tryToProcess(item) {
    try {
        await process(item);
    } catch(error) {
        await resolveAfter3Seconds(item);
    }
}

// Asynchronous method
// Automatic failure for the sake of argument
function process(item) {
    console.log(`Processing ${item}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        setTimeout(() => reject(Error('process error message')), 1)
    );
}

// Asynchrounous method
function resolveAfter3Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Resolved ${x} after 3 seconds.`);
        resolve(x);
    }, 3000));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use `forEach` with `await` like that - `forEach` cannot run asynchronous iterations in serial, only in parallel (and even then, `map` with `Promise.all` would be better). Instead, if you want to use array methods, use `reduce` and `await` the resolution of the previous iteration's Promise:

```js
let items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

processForEach(items);

async function processForLoop(items) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    await tryToProcess(items[i]);
  }
}

async function processForEach(items) {
  await items.reduce(async(lastPromise, item) => {
    await lastPromise;
    await tryToProcess(item);
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

async function tryToProcess(item) {
  try {
    await process(item);
  } catch (error) {
    await resolveAfter3Seconds(item);
  }
}

// Asynchronous method
// Automatic failure for the sake of argument
function process(item) {
  console.log(`Processing ${item}`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => reject(Error('process error message')), 1)
  );
}

// Asynchrounous method
function resolveAfter3Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Resolved ${x} after 3 seconds.`);
    resolve(x);
  }, 3000));
}
```

Also note that if the only `await` in a function is just before the function returns, you may as well just return the Promise itself, rather than have the function be `async`.

Comment: (and even then, `map` with `Promise.all` would be better)... In my case, both asynchronous methods involve IO, so unless  I'm mistaken, using `Promise.all` would be a bad idea. Thanks, helped me out a lot.

Comment: That's only in the case that you want to run the iterations in parallel, but you made it clear that you want to run them in serial, thus the `reduce` method.

Comment: There's really no reason to prefer the `reduce` pattern over `for of` inside `async` functions.

Answer (score 14):

> I'd like to understand why `forEach` doesn't play nicely with `async`/`await`.

It's easier when we consider that `async` is just syntactic sugar for a function returning a promise.

items.[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)(f) expects a function `f` as argument, which it executes on each item one at at time before it returns. It ignores the return value of `f`.

`items.forEach(await tryToProcess)` is nonsense equivalent to `Promise.resolve(tryToProcess).then(ttp => items.forEach(ttp))`

and functionally no different from `items.forEach(tryToProcess)`.

Now `tryToProcess` returns a promise, but `forEach` ignores the return value, as we've mentioned, so it ignores that promise. This is bad news, and can lead to unhandled rejection errors, since all promise chains should be returned or terminated with `catch` to handle errors correctly.

This mistake is equivalent to forgetting `await`. Unfortunately, there's no `array.forEachAwait()`.

items.[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)(f) is a little better, since it creates an array out of the return values from `f`, which in the case of `tryToProcess` would give us an array of promises. E.g. we could do this:

```
await Promise.all(items.map(tryToProcess));
```

...but all `tryToProcess` calls on each item would execute *in parallel* with each other.

Importantly, `map` runs them in parallel. `Promise.all` is just a means to wait for their completion.

#### As a rule...

I always use `for of` instead of `forEach` in `async` functions:

```
for (const item of items) {
  await tryToProcess(item);
}
```

...even when there's no `await` in the loop, just in case I add one later, to avoid this foot-gun.